# ubuntu route traffic to specific remote port via another host

Tags: iptables, routing, nat

There are three servers: A, B and C.

C exposes a service on port 8080 and a firewall rule allows connections from B only.

I need to set up A and B so that A can access C too, through B.

Please note:

- I administer A and B, not C.
- They are independent ubuntu servers, all with direct internet access.
- I can not use the IP address of C as a filter parameter (let's say it's dynamic)
- I can use the port as a filter parameter, because traffic from A directed to port 8080 will always go to C and nowhere else
- A should still be able to contact B normally on other ports and to reach the internet directly

I've read a lot about iptables, but I can't manage to make it work. I think I miss something important.
I also found about [rinetd](http://www.lenzg.net/rinetd/rinetd.html) but I don't know if it can handle my case and I'd like not to add another software if possible.

This is the configuration I tried so far.

**On server A:**

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination IP_OF_B:8080
```

**On server B:**

```
modprobe iptable_nat

vi /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sysctl -p

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s IP_OF_A --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Outcome:**

Data sent from A to C:8080 reaches B:8080 but not C:8080.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't meet the constraint "I can not use the IP address of C as a filter parameter". The easiest thing that comes to mind to do would be to forget iptables on B and set B as a reverse proxy in front of C when A connects. The dynamic part would then be handled by usual DNS resolution made on B

Answer (score 0):

I realize that I missed the dynamic part of server C.

Something like rinetd or xinetd is a perfectly valid option to set up port forwarding. You just should protect it so that only server A can access it.

Then on server A you have two options. You can just connect to server_B:8080 and will be connected to server_C:8080. Server B obviously will have to know how to reach server C.

If you need to use the name of server C, your iptables rule should redirect and traffic for port 8080 to server B. You can verify this by running tcpdump on server B.

Comment: Is the SNAT rule on B alternative to my MASQUERADE rule, or additional? Is the route on A alternative to my DNAT rule? Any chance the route could be added using just the port, not the IP_OF_C as this is dynamic?

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: I found some info about marking the packet with iptables and routing it based on the mark. I don't know if it works because when I add the relevant route I get "RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable". This happens also if I use your old suggestion "route add IP_OF_C via IP_OF_B" so maybe you know how to make this work regardless of the mark?

Comment: What is the purpose of the mark in this case? Did you try the new suggestion?

Comment: The purpose of the mark is to be independent of the IP_OF_C, because in all other cases I need to specify IP_OF_C and I can't. All because routing can't be based on ports alone. So I would mark the packet sent to port 8080 with iptables, then route the packet to B when it has the mark. But when I add the route to B, I get the "Network is unreachable" error. rinetd installed on B would probably allow me to direct a packet to IP_OF_C, but again I need to specify IP_OF_C in the rules and I can't.